Run a secondary SSH server on MacOS Sequoia
I use SSH extensively for intersystem communication within a private (192.x.x.x) network.  Now there is a need to allow only some functions (notably SCP) with a couple of servers from the external world.  So, continuing to use port 22 internally, I would like to set up a more limited SSH server (say on port 10022) for access from the internet (yes, I am aware of the risks and take the responsibility if it all falls apart).
I don't see that question addressed here at Ask Different(ly).  I see there is a /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and it looks pretty standard... is it just a matter of duplicating and modifying that, and doing the same with a plist?  If so, where would I find that plist?
(I found /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist but that says it's disabled.  I also found /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist but I'm not sure that's right either, especially since it is in the Agents (not Daemons) directory.
Currenly, the active lines in /etc/ssh/sshd_config_alt are:
Port xxxxx
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTTY no
PermitUserEnvironment no
ForceCommand internal-sftp

This is what transpires when a person tries to SSH to that system
> ssh -p nnnnn macstudio                                                                                                                                                                 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to macstudio closed.

Of course, the modified port 22 /etc/ssh/sshd_config file limits the incoming connections to local network.

What do you mean with “a more limited SSH server”? How would this second sshd be more restrictive than the standard one?

Having said that: sshd -f /path/to/configfile starts sshd and listens on whatever port you defined in that config file.

It’s not clear why you need a separate server. Why can’t you just forward external port 10022 or whatever to internal port 22 on the router?

@nohillside no-login, scp only ... no-port-forwarding,no-pty,command="scp source target" ssh-dss (see https://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh for starters)

@LincDavis it is about the more restrictive mode.  Internal network still needs full access; external does not.

@nohillside - Thanks.  This is what I have done on other systems, but Mac is so often different.  I will carry on with your sshd suggestion.

If you use public-key authentication, as you should if you’re allowing access from the internet, you can restrict what the key can be used for in the authorized_keys file.

@LincDavis - I am not trying to restrict who can do what.  I am trying to restrict what can be done.  As I should if access is allowed from internet.

If I understand the ServerFault Q&A correctly you referred to above, using authorized_keys is precisely what is proposed there.

Yes @nohillside.  But the goal is different (else this would be a duplicate question).  I want to prevemt those things, but not at the user level.  Same rules apply; difference is in how they're expressed.  System-wide versus user-limited.  I mentioned that article only because you asked how a different configuration would be more restrictive,  Apparently you still don't understand, but that's OK; I have what I need now.  If you make your "sshd -f ..." comment an answer, I will accept it.

Actually, I finally found a part of the solution here: https://gist.github.com/MacLemon/863111

“Uses the same config as standard sshd in /etc/sshd_config except for the port”, so how would you add more protection to the alternate port now? Might be useful to others to know.

@nohillside While the point is FAR outside the original question (and really not pertinent to the question) I have added the details to satisfy curiosity.  I have no security concerns with sharing that much.  But I would appreciate if we could stick to the question (how to run second SSH service) rather than the details of my implementation of that second service.

I‘m currently using Tailscale for remote access, but this is limited to devices where I can install software on, and for my own use. Always good to see that thee are other options.
